# Import text from a file in a WinRT JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime

I'm using the JavaScript Grid App template in Visual Studio Express 2012 to build an app for Windows 8. In the template, the different "pages" in the app are created by page templates called groupedItems.html and itemDetail.html, and the content for each page is taken from a `WinJS.Binding.List` populated with lorem ipsum text stored in the data.js file itself.

What I would like to do instead is populate each list item with HTML content from files that would be stored in the app package, so that the imported content displays within the selected page template just as the sample content does now. I understand that there are a number of ways to read in content from a file asynchronously, but I would prefer to do it synchronously if possible, since all the content would be stored in the app package itself and there shouldn't be any reason I should have to wait for it.

Perhaps the simplest way to put it is that I'm looking for an equivalent of the PHP `include` statement or the CSS `@import` statement to dynamically import my content into the template files, but I haven't found anything that works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

[WinJS.UI.Fragments.renderCopy function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701595.aspx)

[Loading HTML fragments sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Fragments-91f66b07)